# How to get redirect url of http://www.google.com site

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have tried this simple code to get redirect code 307 but failed.

```
string urlRequest = "http://www.google.com";
request = HttpWebRequest.Create(urlRequest) as HttpWebRequest;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Expect response status code is 307 and AbsoluteUri = "https://www.google.com" but not?

Comment: `but not?` What **did** occur?

Comment: @mjwills: it returns 200 status code with response uri is http://www.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not initiate a redirect in this case because it cannot be sure that the client supports https. It seems that google checks the UserAgent header of the request and only initiates a redirection when it can be sure the user agent supports https.

```
string urlRequest = "http://www.google.com";

HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(urlRequest);

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(response.Headers["Location"]);
```

Other request headers will also influence how Google behaves.